# Error when importing qiskit_nature.algorithms.(GroundStateEigensolver, NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory)

Tags: qiskit, vqe, chemistry

I'm trying to import the following elements:

from qiskit_nature.algorithms import (GroundStateEigensolver, NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory)

But it shows the error:
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DistanceMetric32'

This error didn't appear a few weeks ago. I wonder how to solve this problem. Thanks for your helping!

Answer (score 1):

In a fresh environment with `qiskit-nature 0.5.2` in it, I get the following deprecation message:

```
>>> from qiskit_nature.algorithms import (GroundStateEigensolver, NumPyMinimumEigensolverFactory)
<stdin>:1: NatureDeprecationWarning: The qiskit_nature.algorithms.excited_state_solvers package is deprecated as of version 0.5.0 and will be removed no sooner than 3 months after the release. Instead use the qiskit_nature.second_q.algorithms.excited_state_solvers package.
<stdin>:1: NatureDeprecationWarning: The qiskit_nature.algorithms.pes_sampler package is deprecated as of version 0.5.0 and will be removed no sooner than 3 months after the release . Please refer to 'https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/issues/750' for additional information regarding 'extrapolators'.
```

I get the same message when installing from the [current git repository](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-nature/commit/047fbdee80e9525b4d6c68e1d2ca406cb28314ce).

Based on the error, it might be you downgrade a dependency, `scikit-learn` in particular. You can check it out with `pip show scikit-learn`. I'm running `scikit-learn 1.2.1` and it works.

Comment: I use "qiskit-nature 0.5.2" and "scikit-learning 1.2.1" now. But a new bug appears, "ImportError: cannot import name 'class_likelihood_ratios' from 'sklearn.metrics._classification' ".

Comment: that's still a `scikit-learn` error. You might want to redo your environment or submit an issue to https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues